# Postfix+Dovecot: filter email with certain `To:` address

Tags: email, postfix, email-server, dovecot

I have a postfix+dovecot email server. There is one mailbox that was used by the Procurement department in many online shops and the address got disclosed and included in a spam list.

I would like to block any inbound email to this address except for a few trusted domains.

I know I can use `smtpd_sender_restrictions = sender_access` to block inbound email based on sender's conditions, but I need to implement a rule so that, if `To:` field is the filtered email address and the sender is not one of the trusted domains the email is rejected.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The standard lookups in Postfix cannot parse address headers, and even if you were okay with incomplete filters using regex, getting conditional restrictions right will produce unpleasant administrative overhead in your configuration. Better to configure your rules in sieve, spamassassin, rspamd or whatever scriptable filter system(s) you have. If you [edit] your question to include which one(s) you use, someone might help your with advice for the respective configuration language.

Comment: Another thought: why bother with the recipient condition at all? If you want to whitelist some trusted domains just do it. Does it matter if those domains send mails to only a single address or others as well?

Comment: Thank you @anx . We don't have any spam filter (yet).

Comment: @GeraldSchneider We can't block everything and whitelist only a few domains. We need to allow inbound email from any source to most emails except one which should only receive emails from trusted vendors.